# I'm having an error which says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I'm a beginner

Tags: vb.net

im having an error that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." i am retrieving the excel file and import in listview in vb.net please help i am a beginner.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form3

    Public Myexcel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim completed As Boolean = False
    Dim rows As New ExcelRows
    Dim lvitem As ListViewItem


    Private Structure ExcelRows
        Dim id As String
        Dim fname As String
        Dim lname As String
        Dim mi As String
        Dim course As String
        Dim Year As String
        Dim no As String
        Dim picture As String
    End Structure

    Private ExcelRowList As List(Of ExcelRows) = New List(Of ExcelRows)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        OpenFileDialog1.FileName = Nothing

        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If

        If getinfo() = True Then
            For Each xitem In ExcelRowList
                lvitem = ListView1.Items.Add(xitem.no)
                lvitem.SubItems.AddRange(New String() {xitem.id, xitem.lname, xitem.fname, xitem.course, xitem.Year, xitem.picture})


            Next
        End If


    End Sub
    Private Function getinfo() As Boolean

        Myexcel.Workbooks.Open(Me.TextBox1.Text)

        Myexcel.sheet("EXPORT").Activate()
        Myexcel.Range("A3").Activate()

        Do
            If Myexcel.ActiveCell.Value > Nothing Or Myexcel.ActiveCell.Text > Nothing Then

                rows.no = Myexcel.ActiveCell.Value
                Myexcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

                rows.id = Myexcel.ActiveCell.Value
                Myexcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

                rows.lname = Myexcel.ActiveCell.Value
                Myexcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

                rows.fname = Myexcel.ActiveCell.Value
                Myexcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

                rows.mi = Myexcel.ActiveCell.Value
                Myexcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

                rows.course = Myexcel.ActiveCell.Value
                Myexcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

                rows.picture = Myexcel.ActiveCell.Value

                ExcelRowList.Add(rows)

                Myexcel.ActiveCell.Offset(1, -6).Activate()

            Else

                completed = True
                Exit Do

            End If
        Loop
        Myexcel.Workbooks.Close()
        Myexcel = Nothing


        Return completed
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code to find the problem. At the moment, the question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

`MyExcel` object seems nul since you are not creating any instance of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`.

Try:

```
Public Myexcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
```

That should solve the nul-reference exception that you are getting.